# Resampling Time Series Data in Pandas Fill Nans with Previous Data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have some time series data that is mostly quarterly, but reported in year-month-day format for multiple variables and multiple countries, however some variables for some dates have are posted the last day of the quarter and others might post on close to the last day. I would like to perform a resample that aggregates each row to end of quarter of frequency. I have this:

```
Date          Country Var1 Var2 Var3
2012-03-30    China   12   Nan   200
2012-03-31    China   Nan  50    Nan
2012-06-28    China   13   Nan   199
2012-06-30    China   Nan  48    Nan
2012-09-30    China   13   49    200
2012-12-31    China   12   50    201
```

What I want to see is

```
Date          Country Var1 Var2 Var3
2012-03-31    China   12   50    200
2012-06-30    China   13   48    199
2012-09-30    China   13   49    200
2012-12-31    China   12   50    201
```

I tried a couple of different resample ideas. First I tried

```
    df=df.groupby("Country").resample('Q').applymap(lambda x: df.shift(1) if math.isnan(x) else x)
```

Then I tried converting all the Nans to zeros then aggregating by sum, but this is not ideal since I cannot keep track of which data actually are zero and which data were missing.

```
    df=df.fillna(0) 
    df=df.groupby("Country").resample('Q').sum()
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small example with my own dataframe doing what you want.

```
# creating the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 3), columns=['Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3'])

# adding NaN values
df.iloc[1]['Var1'] = np.nan
df.iloc[5]['Var1'] = np.nan

df.iloc[4]['Var2'] = np.nan
df.iloc[6]['Var2'] = np.nan

df

'''
    Var1        Var2        Var3
0   -0.437551   -2.707623   0.726240
1   NaN         2.529733    0.484732
2   0.199278    -0.316516   -0.655426
3   0.732910    -0.638045   -0.706436
4   0.877915    NaN         -1.141384
5   NaN         -2.050228   2.091994
6   -1.119849   NaN         1.222602
7   0.406632    -2.255687   0.742452
'''

# backfilling values in Var2
df['Var2'] = df['Var2'].fillna(method='backfill').dropna()

# dropping NaN rows based on column Var1
df.dropna()

df

'''
    Var1        Var2        Var3
0   -0.437551   -2.707623   0.726240
2   0.199278    -0.316516   -0.655426
3   0.732910    -0.638045   -0.706436
4   0.877915    -2.050228   -1.141384
6   -1.119849   -2.255687   1.222602
7   0.406632    -2.255687   0.742452
'''
```

Comment: This would work, except some columns I wanted to backfill and others I wanted forward fill and have one observation for each quarter. What worked is actually just using resample to end of quarter frequency with an aggregation function of either max or min, which ignores the Nans and just took the observation regardless of whether it was on the last day of the quarter or a few days before, and assigned it to the end of the quarter. Now all my rows are 3/31/YY, 6/30/YY, 9/30/YY, 12/31/YY as opposed to having some rows of 3/28/YY, 6/29/YY, etc